# Modifying Display Object Color

Tags: actionscript-3, colors, actionscript

I'm attempting to change the color of several display objects using colorTransform but can't get it working -

```
private function getChildren(mc:DisplayObjectContainer):Array {
        var children:Array = [];
        for (var i:int = 0; i < mc.numChildren; i++) {
            var child:DisplayObject = mc.getChildAt(i);
            if(child.name == "color1"){
                children.push(child);
            } else if(child.name == "color2"){
                children.push(child);
            }
            if (child is DisplayObjectContainer) {
                var childChildren:Array = getChildren((child as DisplayObjectContainer));         
                children = children.concat(childChildren);
            }
        }
        return children;
    }
```

and in my enter stage event:

```
var mychildren:Array = getChildren(this.spartan);

        for each(var child:DisplayObject in mychildren) {
            if(child.name == "color1"){
                child.transform.colorTransform = _colorTransform1;
            }
            trace(child.name);
```

I've declared the color as `_colorTransform1.color = 0xCCFF00`
My character subsists of several movieclips that are currently either instances of color1:red or color2:green. As a new programmer I'm wondering if I should have proceeded with another method?

```
trace(child.name)
            if(child.name == "color1"){
                trace("found color!")
            }
```

Comment: Don't use name as MC identifier. IIRC Flash does not tolerate two different MC having the same name, so your on-screen instances might not have a name of `color1` or `color2`.

Comment: What should I use instead? The program runs correctly and they movie clips are added to the array it's just that their colors aren't affected by colorTransform.

Comment: Hmmm. Probably trace `_colorTransform1` where you assign it to an MC, probably it's null. If it's null, any color transform applied to the object is cleared.

Comment: It's not null. I recieve RGBA values of the original color.

Comment: @NealDavis - `if(child is` is used correctly.  An instance of a class will never be equal to a class.

Comment: @MadMan - are you sure your `if(child.name == "color1")` statements ever evaluate as true?

Comment: @NealDavis - `is` is an operator, you can find the AS3 specific info about it here:  http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/operators.html#is

Answer (score 1):

Alright, I kind of feel a little stupid right now because the answer was so darn obvious...
While attempting to change the color of the movieclip I had forgotten that the movieclip itself had not loaded yet. To fix this issue all I had to do was call the movieclip frame BEFORE I changed the color.